# mongo collection.find() appears as asynch

Tags: mongodb, meteor, angular, typescript

I can't explain that. Look at my screen:

[image]

I started a little project to understand meteor + mongo + typescript + angular2, but , Unfortunately I having problems with mongo.

In the first log I calling Dots.find().count() and it return 0, after 5s it returns 38.

I know that collection isn't empty, but I didn't found a way to understand when I could have the right result.

I tried with tracker
[tracker documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html)

But is not good for me, because I need to start a function only when all Dots are availables.

Do you have any solution about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you wait for the subscriptions to be ready.  For example:

```
{{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}
{{else}}
 {{/if}}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. I followed the angular2+meteor tutorial here https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/bootstrapping and I'm not sure I can do that :\